# Javascript: How to access local variable in callback function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) form which parse the request. Then along with this request is the file being uploaded.. In [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) you can listen to an event if there's a file.

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm({
    uploadDir: __dirname + '/temp',
    keepExtensions: true
});
```

**This is where I will listen to the event**

```
form.on('file', function(name, file){
   var file = file;
   fs.readFile(file.path, readFileCallback);
});

function readFileCallback(err, contents){
  console.log(file);
  if (err) throw err;
  ....
}
```

My first code was a chain of callback functions and it's kind of hard to read and maintain so I switch with this approach where I would declare functions then call it as a callback instead of like this:

```
form.on('file', function(name, file){
   fs.readFile(file.path, function(err, contents){
      console.log(file);
      if (err) throw err;
      .... 
  });
});
```

With this kind of approach, I could access the outside variable which is `file`. I'm wondering what is the difference between the two in accessing the outside variables. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First one is defined within the scope of parent function so it has access to its enclosing function's local variables. Second one is defined outside and not enclosed.

Comment: Closely related: [*How do JavaScript closures work?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of *scope*. Code has access to the variables declared within the function, its containing function (if any), its containing function (if any), and so on, and then globals.

In your first example, `readFileCallback` is declared outside the `form.on` callback, and so it doesn't have access to things inside the `form.on` callback.

In your second example, the function is *inside* the `form.on` callback, and so it does have access to the things inside it.

Note that in the second example, in theory a new function is created each time the callback is called. That's fine, JavaScript engines are *really fast* at creating functions (and good ones will reuse the code even though a separate function object is created).

Normally you want to create the function at the outermost location where it has access to everything it needs. So in your case, that would be *inside* `form.on`, but *outside* the `readFile` callback. Which is exactly where your second example has it. But you can use a named function like your first example if you like, just put it *in* `form.on`'s callback:

```
form.on('file', function(name, file){
   fs.readFile(file.path, readFileCallback);
   function readFileCallback(err, contents){
      console.log(file);
      if (err) throw err;
      .... 
   }
});
```

Let's take an example where everything had a simple name, and follow through two calls:

```
function outer(outerArg) {
    function middle(middleArg) {
        function inner(innerArg) {
            console.log("innerArg = " + innerArg);
            console.log("middleArg = " + middleArg);
            console.log("outerArg = " + outerArg);
        }

        inner(middleArg.toLowerCase());
    }

    middle(outerArg.toUpperCase());
}
```

`outer` contains `middle` which contains `inner`, and `outer` calls `middle` (and `middle` calls `inner`). A call:

```
outer("Test1");
```

1. `outer` gets the arg `"Test1"`
2. It calls `middle` with `"TEST1"`
3. It calls `inner` with `"test1"`
4. `inner` outputs:

   ```
   innerArg = test1
   middleArg = TEST1
   outerArg = Test1
   ```

So far, so simple, but it's more exciting than that: What if `middle` returns a function that calls `inner`, instead of calling it immediately, and `outer` returns returns `middle`'s return value?

```
function outer(outerArg) {
    function middle(middleArg) {
        function inner(innerArg) {
            console.log("innerArg = " + innerArg);
            console.log("middleArg = " + middleArg);
            console.log("outerArg = " + outerArg);
        }
        function caller() {                         // ***
            inner(middleArg.toLowerCase());         // ***
        }                                           // ***
        return caller;                              // ***
    }

    return middle(outerArg.toUpperCase());          // ***
}
```

Now, calling `outer` doesn't have any output at all:

```
var f = outer("Test2");
```

But then calling the function `middle` returned (`caller`) does:

```
f();
```

Output:

```
innerArg = test2
middleArg = TEST2
outerArg = Test2
```

The arguments still exist after `outer` and `middle` return! But it's even more interesting:

```
var f1 = outer("Test3");
var f2 = outer("Test4");
f2();  // Note -- calling the second one first
f1();
```

Output:

```
innerArg = test4
middleArg = TEST4
outerArg = Test4
innerArg = test3
middleArg = TEST3
outerArg = Test3
```

So that means, *two* `outerArg`s still existed after both calls to `outer` had finished, along with *two* `middleArgs`. How?

They exist on objects attached to the functions:

- Calling `outer` creates an *execution context* (an object), which amongst other things (and leaving out a lot of details) holds the arguments and local variables for that call to `outer`. Let's call it the "outer context." It also has a reference to the execution context containing it (the global context, in our code). Normally that object gets cleaned up when a functon returns...
- ...but `outer` creates a function, `middle`. When you create a function, the current execution context is attached to the function. That's how it has access to the variables and such in that outer context.
- `outer` calls `middle`, creating an inner execution context, and `middle` creates two other function (`inner` and `caller`), which each get that inner context attached to them. `middle` then *returns* `caller`, so `caller` exists after the call to `middle` completes. Since `caller` has a reference to the inner execution context, the context continues to exist (just like any other object), even though `middle` has returned. Since that context has a reference to `inner`, `inner` *also* continues to exist.
- `outer` returns the return value of `middle` (which is `caller`), and so that means `caller` still exists when `outer` returns, which means the inner context it refers to still exists, which means `inner` still exists, *and* the outer context still exists because the inner context has a reference to it.

...which is how `f1` and `f2` have access to those arguments after `outer` returns: When you run them, they look up the values in the contexts attached to them.

Comment: In that case, I would just create my function inside the `event` in order to have access to the `form.on` variables?

Comment: Aha! Now I get the variables outside my functions. Thanks sir.

Comment: @JMSantos: No worries. I added a bit of theory above. Also, there's an article on my blog that may help: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html).

Comment: @T.JCrowder Worth the read sir! Now I understand that when an outer function creates an inner functions it will attach an object, which is the current execution context. That's why the created inner functions would have an access to the outer function variables. Did I got it right?

Comment: @JMSantos: Yup. They have a reference to the context, which contains the variables.